# Is it good practice to use wpdb->query() function?

Tags: functions, database, query, mysql

I am using custom php code to perform data insertion, deletion, updating and other tasks. I am able to insert data into a table in two different ways,

```
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array('id' => NULL, 'name' => '$name', 'email' => '$email', 'city' => '$city'));
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES('', '$name', '$email', '$city')";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Is it a good practice to use `wpdb->query()` function each time by passing my query to the function instead of using the dedicated functions like `insert()` and `delete()` etc? If not, what are the disadvantages of this approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look a bit into the source, you'll see that `$wpdb->insert()` will use [`->query()` under the hood](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L2282). So should be the same, right?

Not that simple. It doesn't just use `->query()` but also [`->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/), which is considered best practice. Meanwhile with your code example you've probably just opened yourself to SQL injections.

The takeaway here: If it is a simple operation and the `->insert()` etc. method work - use them. They're tested and contain little risk. Writing your own queries always carries the risk of opening yourself up to troubles such as SQL injections.

Comment: Simple but useful.... One question, how do these built in functions provide protection against SQL injections?

Comment: @AsmatAli They use [`prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/), which takes care of escaping input. If you use your favorite search engine, you should find enough topics around the topic of "prepared statements"

Answer (score 5):

> Is it a good practice to use wpdb->query() function each time by passing my query to the function instead of using the dedicated functions like insert() and delete() etc?

**No, it is not good practice.** Always prefer the `insert`/`update`/etc methods.

Generally the use of raw SQL in WordPress is a code smell, and using raw SQL when a helper function is available is also bad practice. It implies that the writer is unaware of more convenient APIs with better speed/security, and forces you to reinvent all the fixes and bugs WP developers encountered over the years.

So:

- Use `insert` etc to insert, not `query`, always prefer the more specific function
- Use the 3rd parameter that specifies the format for security reasons
- use `query` as a fallback for more general SQL queries where a specific function is unavailable

  - Always use `prepare` with raw SQL, the examples in your question have SQL injection attack bugs. [See here for how to prepare and secure a raw query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/). `insert` etc will do this automatically if you pass a 3rd parameter
- Don't wrap variables in `'`, use `$name` not `'$name'` or you'll insert `$name` not its value.
- you don't need the `id` set to `null`, if the table was created right with auto increment you can remove that
- you should check if it succeeded or not, don't just assume it worked

```php
$result = $wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    [
        'name'  => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'city'  => $city,
    ],
    [
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
    ]
);
if ( false === $result ) {
    // something went wrong
}
```

### What About Creating Tables?

**Use `dbDelta`,** it will create tables if they don't exist, and update their schema if it changes. No queries to test if the table exists, or update it, or create it, `dbDelta` does it for you. It takes a table creation query as a parameter, and it has to be formatted in a particular way or it won't work.

`wpdb->query` is inappropriate for creating tables.

### A Note on Custom Tables

Just because you used a custom table doesn't mean it's faster/better. Make sure you design your tables with keys and indexes that reflect the types of queries you're going to run. A well built table can be lightning fast, but most tables will perform worse the custom post types at scale due to bad design.

And where possible, avoid writing SQL to interact with your table if you can.